# Userform textbox fills in if Vlookup finds the information related to the numbers inserted

Tags: excel, vba, numbers, vlookup, userform

I have an userform where people have to fill in with data. If the data already exists, when they put the information in the DocumentTitleBox, other textboxes should automatically fill in.

My code works with letters, but not with numbers.

For example, when I put "aaa", it returns the vlookup values. But if I put "123", it won't do anything, even though there is a vlookup for it.

I cannot figure it out why. This is part of my code:

```
Private Sub DocumentTitleBox_Change()

On Error Resume Next
    Result = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(DocumentTitleBox.Value, Worksheets("example").Range("D:E"), 2, False)
    FIND = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(DocumentTitleBox.Value, Worksheets("example").Range("D:E"), 1, False)
On Error GoTo 0

If FIND = DocumentTitleBox.Value Then
    NameBox.Value = Result
End If
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is `DocumentTitleBox` a text box?

Comment: Yes, it is a textbox.

Comment: I placed an answer based on this supposition. Didn't it work?

Comment: Unfortunately not. But thank you anyway for trying!

Comment: Did you see my comment after yours on my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always use this kind of thing. Could be cleaned up and stuff but I like the flexibility and I change stuff all the time so this works for me.

```
Private Sub DocumentTitleBox_Change()

If IsNumeric(DocumentTitleBox.Value) Then
    ReturnRow = Application.IfError(Application.Match(DocumentTitleBox.Value + 0, Worksheets("example").Columns(4), 0), "Not Found")
    Find = Application.IfError(Application.Index(Worksheets("example").Columns(5), ReturnRow), "Not Present")
Else
    ReturnRow = Application.IfError(Application.Match(DocumentTitleBox.Value, Worksheets("example").Columns(4), 0), "Not Found")
    Find = Application.IfError(Application.Index(Worksheets("example").Columns(5), ReturnRow), "Not Present")
End If

If Not Find Like "Not Present" Then
    NameBox.Value = Find
Else
    NameBox.Value = ""
End If

End Sub
```

PS: I don´t know how to avoid the match functions odd behaviour with strings/numbers so I just go with the +0 and IsNumeric trick. One thing to note is case sensitivity, adjust that as needed, right now its not.

Comment: Wow! I did not think about using application.index! Very nice! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

If `DocumentTitleBox` is a text box, try using `DocumentTitleBox.Text` instead of `DocumentTitleBox.Value`.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not solve it. It has the same result, using .text or .value. The input "aaa" works, but any number input won't.

Comment: Did you also use `DocumentTitleBox.Text` in the line `If FIND = DocumentTitleBox.Value Then`?

Comment: Yes, I did. I changed all .values to .text.

Comment: Inserting the line `Debug.Print Result, FIND` after `On Error GoTo 0`, what does it return? I suppose you know that pressing Ctrl + G (in IDE), the Immediate Window, to see the what Debug.Print returns will show up...

Comment: It does not return anything. For the "aaa" value, it returns the vlookup... for any number, it stays blank (I have to leave for a meeting... I will return in 1h. Thank you very much for trying to help me :) )

Comment: Then, are you sure that specific numbers displayed in your text box exist in the lookup range? If yes, please check what format has the vlookup range

Comment: Yes.. I even tried creating fake entries with simple numbers (like "123" or "1").

Comment: I would suggest you to format the vlookup range in the next way: Select the column in discussion and then go 'Data' (Tab) -> 'Text to Columns' -> 'Next' -> 'Next' and 'Finish'. Then, try your code again...

Comment: @Kaue: Did you find time to format the vlookup range as I suggested? Is it something unclear in the way I make my description? It looks, it is a matter of no format matching...

Comment: thank you very much. I tried the format option, but it did not work out. I think there might be a problem with userform format in the textbox. Anyways, the option using .index from Czeskleba worked!

Comment: @Kaue: I am intrigued and I would like to understand what is happening. Vlookup can be a little tricky, but i always solved the appeared issues... Can you post here a link to a dummy workbook, but obtained by copying some rows from the original workbook, having some numeric  fields in the vlookup area? Maybe Google Drive would be the best...